# Longest path in a graph

Tags: graph-algorithm

Given a undirected graph with vertices form 0 to n-1, write a function that will find the longest path (by number of edges) which vertices make an increasing sequence.

What kind of approach would you recommend for solving this puzzle?

Comment: although I am not a mathematician but maybe the exercise is not well defined. If the graph has loops (no matter if directed or undericted) the longest root will be infinite. Hmmm, as this is undirected maybe you can go back and forth on the very same edge hence the longest will be inifinite no matter what, lets see what math guys say, although probably this question should not have been asked here

Comment: "If the graph has loops (no matter if directed or undericted) the longest root will be infinite." This is not correct because of the restriction that the nodes in a path must be increasing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can transform the original graph into a Directed Acyclic Graph by replacing each of the (undirected) edges by a directed edge going towards the node with bigger number.

Then you end up with this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-longest-path-directed-acyclic-graph/

Comment: How does this work?

Say I had undirected graph

```(0) --- (2) --- (1)```

The longest path here is length 2.

By replacing the undirected edges with directed edges going towards the node with the bigger number, I get

```(0) --> (2) <-- (1)```

Now the longest path is length 1?

In your own link, it says:

> The longest path problem for a general graph is not as easy as the shortest path problem... In fact, the Longest Path problem is NP-Hard for a general graph. However, the longest path problem has a linear time solution for directed acyclic graphs.

Comment: @TanWang you seem to forget about the limitation that "vertices make an increasing sequence"

Answer (score 5):

I would do a Dynamic Programming algorithm. Denote *L*(*u*) to be the longest valid path starting at node *u*. Your base case is *L*(*n*-1) = [*n*-1] (i.e., the path containing only node *n*-1). Then, for all nodes *s* from *n*-2 to 0, perform a BFS starting at *s* in which you only allow traversing edges (*u*,*v*) such that *v* > *u*. Once you hit a node for which you've already started at (i.e., a node *u* such that you've already computed *L*(*u*)), *L*(*s*) = longest path from *s* to *u* + *L*(*u*) out of all possible *u* > *s*.

The answer to your problem is the node *u* that has the maximum value of *L*(*u*), and this algorithm is O(*E*), where *E* is the number of edges in your graph. I don't think you can do faster than this asymptotically

EDIT: Actually, the "BFS" isn't even a BFS: it's simply traversing the edges (*s*,*v*) such that *v* > *s* (because you have already visited all nodes *v* > *s*, so there's no traversal: you'll immediately hit a node you've already started at)

So actually, the simplified algorithm would be this:

```
longest_path_increasing_nodes():
    L = Hash Map whose keys are nodes and values are paths (list of nodes)
    L[n-1] = [n-1] # base case
    longest_path = L[n-1]
    for s from n-2 to 0: # recursive case
        L[s] = [s]
        for each edge (s,v):
            if v > s and length([s] + L[v]) > length(L[s]):
                L[s] = [s] + L[v]
        if length(L[s]) > length(longest_path):
            longest_path = L[s]
    return longest_path
```

**EDIT 2022-03-01:** Fixed typo in the last if-statement; thanks user650654!

Comment: Good algo.  Looks like it should be `if length(L[s]) > length(longest_path):` on the third to last line.

Comment: Is [s] in L[s] referring to a list with only s in it or all paths of s?

Comment: `L[s]` is the longest path that ends at node `s`. The statement `L[s] = [s]` means "The longest path ending at node `s` (i.e., `L[s]` on the left side of the assignment) is the path only containing node `s` (i.e., `[s]` on the right side of the assignment

Answer (score 1):

There are algorithms like Dijkastras algorithm which can be modified to  find the longest instead of the shortest path.

Here is a simple approach:

- Use a recursive algorithm to find all paths between 2 nodes.
- Select the longest path.

If you need help with the recursive algorithm just ask.

Comment: Dijkstra's would not be optimal: it would be O(*E* log *E*), whereas the problem can be solved in O(*E*) as per my solution

Comment: "algorithms like Dijkastras algorithm which can be modified to find the longest instead of the shortest path" Also: this statement is very misleading. Dijkstra's can be modified to find the longest path if there are no negative edge weights and there are no cycles. This happens to be the case here ("by number of edges" = no negative edge weights, and "vertices make an increasing sequence" = acyclic), so we happen to be able to use a modified Dijkstra's here (although it's not the fastest possible algorithm), but not generally

Comment: I think it's clear that we can assume a common positive weight for the questioners problem. In my mind searching the longest path when there exists a path with loops makes not much sense. In this case we know the length of thew longest path. If that option is on the table, first proof if path with loops exists.

Comment: "In my mind searching the longest path when there exists a path with loops makes not much sense." This problem does not allow paths with cycles. OP specified a restriction that "vertices make an increasing sequence". If you had a cycle, you would eventually hit a point where the vertex number decreases (e.g. 1 -> 2 -> **3 -> 1**), so this restriction disallows cycles