# Farthest node in array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, nodes

I want a function an array of hyphenated letters representing paths between those two nodes. For example: `["a-b","b-c","b-d"]` means that there is a path from node a to b (and b to a), b to c, and b to d. My program should determine the longest path that exists in the graph and return the length of that path. In this case, the output should be `2` because of the paths a-b-c and d-b-c. No cycles should exist in the graph and every node will be connected to some other node in the graph.

Other examples:

```
Input: ["b-e","b-c","c-d","a-b","e-f"]
Output: 4

Input: ["b-a","c-e","b-c","d-c"]
Output: 3
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an existing package like [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/)? How do you handle cycles `(a-b-c-a-b-c....)`? Have you tried to develop an algorithm yourself and if so where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I could use it but it would be better to use numpy

Comment: No cycles should exist in the graph and every node will be connected to some other node in the graph.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Longest path in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47998220/longest-path-in-a-graph)

Comment: I am testing the solution

Comment: @ramzeek Your dupe target isn't correct. That question is finding the longest path in a graph with nodes that have some preimposed ordering; you can reduce it to finding the longest path in a DAG. On the other hand, OP's question does _not_ assign any additional properties to the nodes; in fact, this problem is NP-Complete (by reduction from Hamiltonian Path). It's a subtle difference, but it's an important one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following solution

##### Code:

```py
def find_farthest_nodes(input_path: str):
    path_list = [path.replace('-', '') for path in input_path]
    # print('path_list:', path_list)
    # All points
    node_list = list(set(''.join(path_list)))  # ['b', 'd', 'f', 'a', 'c', 'e']
    # print('node_list:', node_list)
    node_list.sort()  # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    # print('node_list:', node_list)

    # Search all one step paths to a point
    def search_one_step_path(node: str):
        one_step_paths_list = []
        for path in path_list:
            if node in path:
                if node == path[1]:
                    path = path[1] + path[0]
                one_step_paths_list.append(path)
        return one_step_paths_list

    # Search all N-step path of a point
    def search_n_step_path(node_degree_list: list):
        n_step_path_list = []
        for path in node_degree_list:
            # Search for all first-order paths of the n + 1 point
            # For example: search the first order path of the 3rd point
            one_step_paths_list = search_one_step_path(path[-1])
            # Delete the path containing the previous order (n-th point)
            # For example: delete the path to the second point based on the 2-step path
            one_step_paths_list = [p for p in one_step_paths_list if path[-2] not in p]
            #  The original n-step path + all steps in this node, get all the N + 1-stage path under this node
            n_step_path_part_list = [path[:-1] + p for p in one_step_paths_list]
            #  The path to all nodes is added together to form all N + 1-stage paths of origin
            n_step_path_list.extend(n_step_path_part_list)
        return n_step_path_list

    for node in node_list:
        node_degree_list = search_one_step_path(node)
        length, farthest_node_length = 1, 1
        farthest_path, highest_degree_node_list = node_degree_list, node_degree_list

        while True:
            higher_degree_node_list = search_n_step_path(node_degree_list)
            if higher_degree_node_list:
                highest_degree_node_list = higher_degree_node_list
                length += 1
            else:
                break
            node_degree_list = higher_degree_node_list
        if length > farthest_node_length:
            farthest_node_length = length
            farthest_path = highest_degree_node_list
    
    return farthest_node_length,farthest_path


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Enter the adjacent path to get the farthest path
    input_paths = [["a-b","b-c","b-d"], ["b-e","b-c","c-d","a-b","e-f"], ["b-a","c-e","b-c","d-c"]]
    for input_path in input_paths:
        farthest_node_length, farthest_path = find_farthest_nodes(input_path)
        print(f'For {input_path} path the farthest node length: {farthest_node_length} and one of farthest node paths: {farthest_path}')
```

##### Output:

```sh
For ['a-b', 'b-c', 'b-d'] path the farthest node length: 2 and one of farthest node paths: ['dba', 'dbc']
For ['b-e', 'b-c', 'c-d', 'a-b', 'e-f'] path the farthest node length: 4 and one of farthest node paths: ['febcd']
For ['b-a', 'c-e', 'b-c', 'd-c'] path the farthest node length: 3 and one of farthest node paths: ['ecba']
```